# Docker-api check if the method is running successfully

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using rails 6 api and ı try to create docker container with docker-api gem . How can I check if the method is running successfully? I'm trying something but doesn't work.

```
class ContainerController < ApplicationController
      def info
        @container = Docker::Container.create('Image' => 'alpine', 'Tty' => true, 'name' => 'lorem',
                                              'ExposedPorts' => { '1234/tcp' => {} },
                                              'HostConfig' => {
                                                  'PortBindings' => {
                                                      '1234/tcp' => [{ 'HostPort' => '1234', 'HostIp' => '0.0.0.0' }]
                                                  }
                                              })

       
          if Docker::Error
           render json: "error",status: :created
          else
           @container.start
           render json: @container,status: :created
          end

      end
```

Comment: What are you getting in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are just creating a container without RUN. [Docs](https://github.com/swipely/docker-api#containers)

You can check your container and make sure is't running currently or not.

```
 puts @container.json 
 #outputs: {... "State"=>{"Running"=>false}}
```

Check docs to RUN the container

```
@container.start
```